# Save Javascript Value Using C# Async Postback

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an Asp TextBox called `txt_edit_content` whose value is being copyed and manipulated using a JavaScript Wysiwyg. The formatted text is stored in a JavaScript variable that I can access like so:

```
var data = CKEDITOR.instances.<%=txt_edit_content.ClientID%>.getData();
```

What I'm attempting to do is send that value back to the server. So, I have registered the following JavaScript function with the `Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager`

```
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    try{
        var data = CKEDITOR.instances.<%=txt_edit_content.ClientID%>.getData();
        console.log("Textbox Before: " + $('#<%=txt_edit_content.ClientID%>').val());
        console.log("    Javascript: " + data);
        $('#<%=txt_edit_content.ClientID%>').val(data);
        console.log(" Textbox After: " + $('#<%=txt_edit_content.ClientID%>').val());
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error:" + err.message);
    }
}
```

And registering it like so:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
```

The JavaScript console output before the POST is made looks like so:

```
Textbox Before: 1234 
    Javascript: <p>1234567</p> 
 Textbox After: <p>1234567</p>
```

The issue I'm running into is that the value, even though it is being changed on page, isn't being sent to the server. However the 'Textbox Before' value is being sent. How can I get the value out of my JavaScript and into my code?

**Edit:**
I can get this code to work using a `PostBackTrigger` but not `AsyncPostBackTrigger` on the 'Save' button. However, I need (would like) to use the `AsyncPostBackTrigger` on the 'Save' button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work without using another field or having to add a handler to the `PageRequestManager`

By creating the following JavaScript function

```
function SaveWysiwig() {
    try{
        var data = CKEDITOR.instances.<%=txt_edit_content.ClientID%>.getData();
        $('#<%=txt_edit_content.ClientID%>').val(data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error:" + err.message);
    }
}
```

Then calling it through my save button like so:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="savePage" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClientClick="SaveWysiwig();" OnClick="SavePage" />
```

I was able to get the JavaScript value stored in my textbox then pulled with my code-behind.

Answer (score 1):

Use an update panel and wrap a Hidden field in it.  Then in your handler, set the value of the hidden field.

```
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    try{
        var data = CKEDITOR.instances.<%=txt_edit_content.ClientID%>.getData();
        console.log("Textbox Before: " + $('#<%=txt_edit_content.ClientID%>').val());
        console.log("    Javascript: " + data);
        $('#<%=txt_edit_content.ClientID%>').val(data);
        console.log(" Textbox After: " + $('#<%=txt_edit_content.ClientID%>').val());
        $('#<%=hidValue.ClientID%>').val(data);

    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error:" + err.message);
    }
}
```

Now in your code behind you can get the value of hidValue.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work, it has the same issue as before.

Comment: Are you saying that hidValue has the same value as the old text box value?

Comment: The value doesn't get sent to the server. If I have`<asp:HiddenField ID="hidValue" runat="server" />` and use the JavaScript `$('#<%=hidValue.ClientID%>').val(data);` the value sent to the server is blank. It is as if the page is tracking values separately.

Comment: However this will work on if the 'Save' button is on a `PostBackTrigger` instead of an `AsyncPostBackTrigger`